# How to cache content in UIWebView for faster loading later on?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios

I notice that the iphone safari caches content so that your page load for later is much faster much like a desktop browser. So take mobile gmail web page for example, the first load is quite slow (5-10 secondS). But if I close the tab and reopen the page again, it's very quick (1 second).

However, this behavior is not the same if you load the content through a UIWebView in your app. Am I missing some settings? How do I make the UIWebView cache the content automatically without going through the hassle of saving the content myself?

Answer (score 23):

The key is: `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad`

```
NSData *urlData;
NSString *baseURLString =  @"mysite.com";
NSString *urlString = [baseURLString stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval: 10.0]; 
NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:nil]; 

if (connection)
{ 
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request];

    NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURLString];
    [htmlString release];
}

[connection release];
```

Comment: The iOS documentation says that NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad "Specifies that the existing cache data should be used to satisfy a request, regardless of its age or expiration date." That is generally not what you want, since it ignores cache policy headers like max-age and so forth. So this doesn't sound like a good general answer. The seemingly best choice is "NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy" but this seems to do nothing.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *stringurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:stringurl];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:15.0];
[uiwebview loadRequest:theRequest];
```

It will load a url first time then looks for for only the content changes..,if there is no updates in the url content it will load from the cache(local storage).

Comment: Can you explain it a bit?

Comment: It will load a url first time then looks for for only the content changes..,if there is no updates in the url content it will load from the cache(local storage).

Comment: Yeah, but do this in answer

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this discussion thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1588010) it would appear there isn't any OS-level caching possible with `UIWebView`. Based on experience I've noticed that Safari on my iPhone OS device doesn't cache its web pages (e.g., hitting the back button in Safari does not reload the old page from a cache).

Comment: Seems cache only works on HTML 5 manifest which is used when offline.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a couple of apps that cache pages to the Documents folder, then compare the time-stamps of the cached & web pages before loading the new web page.  So the basic flow is:

```
if (fileIsInCache)
    if (cacheFileDate > webFileDate)
        getCachedFile
    else
        getFileFromWeb
        saveFileToCache
else
    getFileFromWeb
    saveFileToCache

stuffFileIntoUIView

maybeReduceCache
```

You still have to hit the web to get the headers, but that's typically much faster than downloading a whole page/image/file.