# Loading performance between a UIWebView and Safari is considerably different, any pointers?

Tags: iphone, performance, ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView in an iPhone application I am building.  It's job is to load up a URL.  The code I use is:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:providedURL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

This is in viewDidLoad.

I have noticed that it takes around 18 seconds for the page to load in my app....but when using Safari it takes 5-8 seconds.  Has anyone run into this issue before?  Does it have anything to do with how I'm forming my request?

Comment: Did you clear the cache in Safari for a fair timing comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely because Safari has cached the resources of the site already.  A basic UIWebView does not do any caching by itself.  You'll have to implement that yourself.  See a question about that here:

[How to cache content in UIWebView for faster loading later on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348696)