# How to maintain sessions in a UIwebview in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, caching, uiwebview

I have a UIWebview. Let's say I open google in that view and then I press the back button and come back to Webview page again. Is it possible to see google (already opened) instead of loading that page again?

Comment: I also edited your tags for "caching"; you can check out other questions under that tag

Answer (score 0):

**Yes indeed, it is called caching.**  It basically saves the page in memory so that it can be called later without loading.  The only major problem is that if your "cache" (save) a page, if the page is updated on the internet it will not be updated in your app until the page is refreshed and loaded.

There is a lot of information on caching for iOS, just search on the Internet.  A helpful link I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348696/how-to-cache-content-in-uiwebview-for-faster-loading-later-on) Stackoverflow question which shows you how to cache content.