# How to save dynamic webpage in cache using UIWebview in Swift 3

Tags: ios, caching, uiwebview, swift3

I am developing an application(Swift 3 using UIWebview). I need to load webpages into webview and save  some webpages into cache. If there is not internet user will able to see those pages. But I am confused on how to save whole webpage in cache. The main thing is we need to show pages back even if there is not internet.

I used the following documention : http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/
and https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlcache

```
let url = NSURL(string: load_url1)
let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as! URL,cachePolicy: NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.returnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 60)
self.webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest);
```

Has anyone implemented this before. Please provide some demo code as this is my first attempt on cache

Comment: but your question is too broad to answer

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348696/how-to-cache-content-in-uiwebview-for-faster-loading-later-on

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i tried this one but pages not loaded in offline

Comment: what the issue u faced

Comment: its loaded only for static pages. I am getting problem when rendering pages with help of JSON data

Answer (score 8):

Just use

```
let url = URL(string: urlString)
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
urlRequest.cachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
```

Comment: Excellent. Working perfect. Thank you.

Comment: I am getting black screen

Comment: You can define the cachePolicy when initiating the URLRequest by doing something like **URLRequest(url: URL!, cachePolicy:.returnCacheDataElseLoad)** .This is helpful in inline calls in SwiftUI.