# How to store the image in webView?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, webview

As I am a newbie, I don't know how to google to solve this question.

Then I ask this question.

Now, I have a list in an `Html` show in the WebView in the App.
like this:

[image]

You can see an image located in the left area in an item of the list.

Is there a way to store the list image.

How to store the image Use the `javascript`?

or

How to store the image by using the iOS webView API?

How to store the image by using the Android webView API?

What I need:

In a week or several days, the app requests the same network image once.
Now, my app requests the image every time. This way waste user's mobile phone traffic.

If you don't know my expression. I know a perfect library named `SDWebImage`.
In iOS APP, the `SDWebImage` can store the image in a week.

Comment: Are you loading html or a website through url?

Comment: partially duplicate (iOS): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348696/how-to-cache-content-in-uiwebview-for-faster-loading-later-on

Comment: @GursheeshSingh Yes, I load my HTML with `webview`.

Comment: Can you post it here

Comment: @GursheeshSingh I set the Html as the local file in the app.

Comment: Can you post the html code?

Comment: @GursheeshSingh  Must I post my code? I use zepto.js ajax to request the server.

Comment: the HTML code which came back to your application to display it in webview post it here

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading it using `WebView`, you should consider caching the WebPage. You can enable the cache for `WebView` using this property:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK

```
mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

Else if you are using URL's to load the image into custom ListView or RecyclerView, this library could help you out:

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader